# docker-compose - PHP instance seems not to communicate with database service

Tags: postgresql, docker, symfony, docker-compose, devops

I'm developing a project based on the Github template **dunglas/symfony-docker** to which I want to add a **postgres** database..

It seems that my docker compose.yml file is incorrectly configured because the communication between PHP and postgres is malfunctioning.
Indeed when I try to perform a symfony migration, doctrine returns me the following error :

> password authentication failed for user "postgres"

When I inspect the PHP logs I notice that PHP is waiting after the database

> php_1  | Still waiting for db to be ready... Or maybe the db is not reachable.

My docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  php:
    links:
      - database
    build:
      context: .
      target: symfony_php
      args:
        SYMFONY_VERSION: ${SYMFONY_VERSION:-}
        SKELETON: ${SKELETON:-symfony/skeleton}
        STABILITY: ${STABILITY:-stable}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      # Run "composer require symfony/orm-pack" to install and configure Doctrine ORM
      DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
      # Run "composer require symfony/mercure-bundle" to install and configure the Mercure integration
      MERCURE_URL: ${CADDY_MERCURE_URL:-http://caddy/.well-known/mercure}
      MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL: https://${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}/.well-known/mercure
      MERCURE_JWT_SECRET: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}

  caddy:
    build:
      context: .
      target: symfony_caddy
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME:-localhost, caddy:80}
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTPS
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTP/3
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: udp

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-13}-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-ChangeMe}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-symfony}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

volumes:
  php_socket:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  db-data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

extract of my .env file :

```
POSTGRES_DB=proximityNL
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@database:5432/proximityNL?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
```

Can you help me ?

Best regards ..

UPDATE :
Indeed I understood on Saturday that it was just necessary to remove orphan ..

```
docker-compose down --remove-orphans --volumes
```

Comment: I struggled with this for one entire day, as in 24 hours. I'm not sure what made it work but my configurations in the .env file is:

`DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@database:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"`

And in the docker-compose.yml:
`DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}`

Answer (score 1):

When running in a container, 127.0.0.1 refers to the container itself. Docker compose creates a virtual network where each container has its own IP address. You can address the containers by their service names.

So your connection string should point to `database:5432` instead of `127.0.0.1:5432` like this

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@database:5432/proximityNL?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
```

You use `database` because that's the service name of your postgresql container in your docker compose file.

Comment: Thank you for your responsiveness.
I made the changes you suggested.I still have the same PHP log, but the error returned by doctrine changed, it seems invalidate the connection constants.
`password authentication failed for user "postgres"`
Is it possible that environment variables are not taken into account in the file docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @JonathanMorel Based on the username and password environment variables your set on your postgres container, I would think username and password in your connection string should be `postgres-ChangeMe:postgres-symfony`

Comment: the `$ (FOO: -bar)` syntax just allows replacement in the case where the variable is undefined.
For example :
`FOO = "a value"
echo $ (FOO: -replacement)
` will return ` "a value"` and `echo $ (BAR: -replacement2)` will return `"replacement2"`
If in doubt I tried to provide the values directly by replacing the variables with the values the result is the same ..

Comment: I didn't know that. In that case, your connection string looks good. Environment variable substitution must also be taking place, since you get the database URL from the .env file. I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: One thing though: Postgres only creates the user and database if the database volume is empty. If you're using an old volume that has been created with another user, password or database name, you might get the error you see. Try with a fresh `db_data` volume.

Answer (score 0):

In docker you can call images via the name of it.

So try to use the name of the docker image for your config

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@database:5432/proximityNL?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
```

and maybe add an link between your php and database image

```
services:
  php:
  links:
   - database
```

This is the way how i am connect a java app with an mysql db.

Comment: Thank you for your responsiveness.
I made the changes you suggested.I still have the same PHP log, but the error returned by doctrine changed, it seems invalidate the connection constants.
`password authentication failed for user "postgres"`
Is it possible that environment variables are not taken into account in the file docker-compose. Yml?

Comment: You set the pw for the user in the env of the docker-compose and try to overwrite it in your conf. But when you set it, the .yaml it is set for the service and the pw in your config is just to save the pw from the service and not to set it for it. Long term short: your pw is ChangeMe

Answer (score 0):

Docker should map DNS resolution from the Docker Host into your containers.

Networking in Compose [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Because of that, you DB URL should look like:
"postgresql://postgres:postgres@database:5432/..."

Comment: Thank you for your responsiveness. I made the changes you suggested.I still have the same PHP log,
`Still waiting for db to be ready... Or maybe the db is not reachable.`
 but the error returned by doctrine changed, it seems invalidate the connection constants. 
`password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Answer (score 0):

I understood on Saturday that it was just necessary to remove orphan

```
docker-compose down --remove-orphans --volumes
```